# tex4ht problem with matlab-prettifier package. lstlisting code shows differently from lstinputlisting

Tags: luatex, tex4ht, matlab, make4ht

It seems like a lost case using Matlab code in Latex when it comes to tex4ht.

I switched to using `matlab-prettifier` package instead of `mcode` package to load Matlab code in Latex since I found too many problem with tex4ht using mcode. I already posted 2 questions on that. [mcode-package-with-tex4ht-and-lualatex-produce-invalid-html-for-strings-in-matla](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296139/mcode-package-with-tex4ht-and-lualatex-produce-invalid-html-for-strings-in-matla)  and  [tex4ht-scrambles-some-matlab-code-when-using-mcode-package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290014/tex4ht-scrambles-some-matlab-code-when-using-mcode-package)

Now I found another problem with using `matlab-prettifier` package. The problem is that string quotes are removed from Matlab code when using `\lstinputlisting` vs. when using `lstlisting` for same code.

I have tried changing the `escapechar` but nothing worked. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{foo_x.m}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab,style=Matlab-editor]
% ode45 "is based on an explicit Runge-Kutta formula...
% program"
%

function foo_x
clear; clf; clc;
x=10;
fprinf('this is %d\n',x);
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Same code is in the file  `foo_x.m`  as shown above inside the latex file. Exactly same listing. To save you time making `foo_x.m` and copy the code to it to reproduce this, here is [link to the m file](http://12000.org/tmp/022616/foo_x.m)

This is what make4ht produces in HTML:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the difference from the first listing and the second listing for same code. The first one do not have single quote around the strings.

Compiled using

```
 make4ht --lua -u foo.tex
```

Here is what lualatex produces. Same code in both cases.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I removed `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` from the MWE but it made no difference. I can keep trying adding and removing packages and changing options, but this is getting tiring really. It seems using Matlab code in Listing with `make4ht --lua` is a problem. When I remove the `--lua` option it works:

```
make4ht -u foo.tex
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but I need to use `--lua` option with `make4ht`. So what is the solution?

TL 2015 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. `\lstset` do not work the same way with tex4ht as it does with lualatex. When I changed the the order of options to `\lstset` the problem went away!  I simply changed

```
\lstset{
  language           = Matlab,
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true  
}
```

to

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  language           = Matlab,
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true  
}
```

and now the string quotes are there!  Moving `language= Matlab` above `basicstyle= \mlttfamily` brings the problem back.  So the solution is this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}           
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  language           = Matlab,
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true  
}
\else
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
  language           = Matlab,
  style              = Matlab-editor,
  basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
  escapechar         = `,
  mlshowsectionrules = true  
}
\fi

\begin{document}

Now showing lstinputlisting

\lstinputlisting{foo_x.m}

Now showing lstlisting

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Matlab,style=Matlab-editor]
% ode45 "is based on an explicit Runge-Kutta formula...
% program"
%

function foo_x
clear; clf; clc;
x=10;
fprinf('this is %d\n',x);
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result of `make4ht --lua -u foo.tex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another problem I found, is that if I use `\usepackage{times}` then tex4ht also now loses the quotes around the code!  Just adding `\usepackage{times}` in the MWE above causes the quotes to go away again.

So two things to watch for: do not use `\usepackage{times}` and make sure to put `language = Matlab,` after `basicstyle= \mlttfamily` when compiling with `make4ht` and `--lua`. I suspect these 2 things lead to the same basic encoding problem with tex4ht when using `--lua` option.

So many package clashes and option conflicts. It is a nightmare to keep track of all these things.